# Problems with WeChat social login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wechat, wechat-auth

I have a developer account that has completed all the certification procedures for using the WeChat open platform.
and I developing a social login function through oauth2 of the WeChat open platform.
The QR code will be displayed on the website when i make a Weixinlogin authorization.
After that, I understand that when the user scans the QR code through the WeChat app, the GET request is received through 'redirect_uri'. but, there are no any requests. What should I do?

i opened the 'https://open.weixin.qq.com/connect/qrconnect?appid=appid1111&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2Fv1%2Fwechat%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=snsapi_login&state=3d6be0a4035d839573b04816624a415e#wechat_redirect' link in google chrome browser.
then showed the QR code for the web application i created.
and i scnas the QR code through the WeChat app, and i expected GET request callback should come in via 'https://test.com/v1/wechat/callback'. but, there are no any requests.